# how to redirect non php extension url to php extension url htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have added **.php** extension to all my pages in wordpress through functions.php.

My Code -

```
<?php
// Do NOT include the opening PHP tag

// Add .PHP to page permalinks
add_action('init', 'ss_php_pages', -1);
function ss_php_pages() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    
    if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.php')){
            $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.php';
    }
    
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Remove slash from page permalinks
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash_on_ss',66,2);
function no_page_slash_on_ss($string, $type){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes==true && $type == 'page'){
        return untrailingslashit($string);
    }else{
       return $string;
      }
}
```

Now I want to redirect my old link **(example.com/demo)** to new link **(example.com/demo.php)**..
I have many pages there so I can't add redirection for each manually.

Additional information:
I have added .php extension to my Wordpress pages (example.com/demo + .php). Now My Old Links (example.demo or example.com/anything) which were without .php, got 404 because I have added .php to them so they have modified. Now I want to redirect my all old links like example.com/demo to example.com/demo.php or example.com/xyz to example.com/xyz.php to not to loss traffic or getting broken link.

Comment: Please share your htacces file in your question thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 htaccess file is empty sir

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 what happened

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand your question, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: tell me what you can't understand

Comment: I believe I had already mentioned in my answer's comments section, I am not understanding: 1- FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite. 2- Do you want to always rewrite to 1 file(which is added.php(which you mentioned in my answer's comment)? I have read your question but its not clear to me so I asked these questions.

Comment: 1. I have added .php extension to my Wordpress pages (example.com/demo + .php)                  2.Now My Old Links (example.demo or example.com/anything) which were without .php, got 404 because i have added .php to them so they have modified.                                                                               3.Now i want to redirect my all old links like example.com/demo to example.com/demo.php or example.com/xyz to example.com/xyz.php to not to loss traffic or getting broken links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following htaccess Rules. Make sure htaccess is present in root folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
##User is using wordpress without this rule it was adding .php to home page too which was NOT needed, hence this rule is been added.
RewriteRule ^/?$ / [R=301,END]

##Major rules for links which are non php and should be served with php format files.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

For JS/CSS rewrite: You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: i am hitting a page of my site . example.com/lake but it's showing 404 error not redirecting to example.com/lake.php

Comment: @E-Gyan, ok please do let me know path of your htaccess AND your lake.php file complete path here.

Comment: hey, lake.php isn't a file. it's a page of wordpress (/lake) in which i have added .php. read question again

Comment: @E-Gyan, So any page should go to added.php? If that is non-existent one? Please confirm once and I will edit rules then.

Comment: yes you can redirect non-exist one also. because i am not using seperate 404 page (like example.com/404), i am just showing 404 template on same page (example.com/non-exists-one) on that page it will show 404. so it doesn't matter if it is example.com/non-exists-one or non-exists-one.php . but please don't add .php to 404 pages and any other except of pages slugs, which are accessable

Comment: @E-Gyan, Based on your latest comments, could you please try my edited solution htaccess now? Let me know how it goes. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: It is working but my styles css files broken and it is adding .php to homepage also (example.com/.php)

Comment: my css and js files added in head in this format <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">  so now how i have to change it to get worked it without base

Comment: @E-Gyan, please remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$` once and let me know then how it goes,'

Comment: okay, after removing this line it is working (redirecting non php to .php) but it applies on homepage too –

Comment: @E-Gyan, ok so home page condition is not working gotcha. So from which file(index,php or any other file) your home page should be served?

Comment: i am using a wordpress theme and running on wordpress so i don't know which file is responsible for homepage and which should be

Comment: @E-Gyan, but usually this is the condition which avoids home page from urls checking not sure why its not working here. try changing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$` TO `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/?\s` once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: not working again. this one homepage condition line making all code worst. if i use this condition line in code no redirections were made. but after just removing this condition line it got worked (but in this case without condition homepage also redirect to example.com/.php throws 404).

Comment: @E-Gyan, try changing from `RewriteRule ^/?$ / [END]` TO `RewriteRule ^/?$ / [R=301,END]` once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Boom ! It is working ! my only wordpress pages redirecting, home and 404 not adding .php thanks sir.

Comment: @E-Gyan, GREAT, good to hear :) very happy to help. Does that link helped? Please do let me know. Also what exact rules worked for you? sorry there were so many suggestions made by me need to know what worked for you, so that I can make an edit to my answer.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?$ / [END] TO RewriteRule ^/?$ / [R=301,END] that worked yup maybe link worked !maybe but your ruled 100% worked

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your `non-php` pages to `php` using RewriteRule directive in your WordPress htaccess.

At the top of your htaccess file , put the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not working brother. without extension only redirecting to 404

Comment: not working also. cache cleared, htaccess is in root (example.com/.htacesss), code is at the top of htaccess before default htacesss code.

Comment: @e-gyan Sorry there was a typo . The edited code should work.